# Change the value of sigma using the fitcsvm function in Matlab

Tags: matlab, kernel, svm

I wanted to know how to go about changing the value of sigma using the fitcsvm in Matlab.

I am using this command:

```
cl3 = fitcsvm(X,Y,'KernelFunction','rbf', 'Standardize',true,'BoxConstraint',2,'ClassNames',[-1,1]);
```

and wanted to plot the SVM generated boundries for different sigma values.  Where do you include the sigma values?

Thanks for your time and help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `KernelScale` parameter to set g, f.e.:

```
cl3 = fitcsvm(X, Y, 'KernelFunction', 'rbf', 'KernelScale', 0.1, ...
             'Standardize', true, 'BoxConstraint', 2, 'ClassNames', [-1,1]);
```